# Google Cloud Platform Runtimes Common FTL AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, containers

Would you please help me with this problem. I am trying to make a dockerfile by ftl and get an error.

My system:

```
python3 --version => Python 3.7.3
node -v => v12.18.0
npm -v => 6.14.4
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType =>
Software:
System Software Overview:
System Version: macOS 10.15.5 (19F101)
Kernel Version: Darwin 19.5.0
Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
Boot Mode: Normal
Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
System Integrity Protection: Enabled
```

I follow these steps:

```
1- mkdir examples
2- cd examples
3- npm init -y
4- echo 'console.log("hello world");' >> file.js
5- echo 'FROM node:12.18.0-alpine' >> dockerfile
6- echo 'WORKDIR /app' >> dockerfile
7- echo 'cp file.js ./' >> dockerfile
8- echo 'CMD ["node","file.js"]' >> dockerfile
9- python ./ftl.par --directory=$(pwd) --name=image --tar_base_image_path=$(pwd)
```

NOTE: flt.par from https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-container-tools/ftl/node/latest/ftl.par

I received an error:

```
INFO FTL version node-v0.18.0
INFO Beginning FTL build for node
INFO FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None
INFO FTL arg passed: cache_repository None
INFO FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path /Users/smhmayboudi/Developer/kaniko/examples
INFO FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False
INFO FTL arg passed: builder_output_path None
INFO FTL arg passed: name image
INFO FTL arg passed: ttl 168
INFO FTL arg passed: global_cache False
INFO FTL arg passed: cache True
INFO FTL arg passed: upload True
INFO FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False
INFO FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True
INFO FTL arg passed: base None
INFO FTL arg passed: output_path None
INFO FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.18.0
INFO FTL arg passed: cache_salt
INFO FTL arg passed: directory /Users/smhmayboudi/Developer/kaniko/examples
INFO FTL arg passed: entrypoint None
INFO FTL arg passed: additional_directory None
INFO FTL arg passed: destination_path srv
INFO FTL arg passed: verbosity NOTSET
INFO starting: full build
INFO starting: builder initialization
INFO builder initialization took 0 seconds
INFO full build took 0 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"main", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "./ftl.par/main.py", line 65, in
File "./ftl.par/main.py", line 52, in main
File "./ftl.par/main/ftl/node/builder.py", line 31, in init
File "./ftl.par/main/ftl/common/builder.py", line 89, in init
File "./ftl.par/containerregistry/client/docker_name.py", line 182, in init
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

Comment: Could you provide more clarification on where/how you are receiving this error? With which GCP product you are getting this issue?

Comment: Please check this link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/runtimes-common/tree/master/ftl plus I fill out an issue on their GitHub.